# how to add codecs to media element

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, media-player

I am working on windows 8 application.I have to make a media player. For quick start i used built in media element to make media player. 
But media element do not support avi and mkv files! How to add codecs that would make media element play even mkv and avi files. 
Thanks in advance.